# Is it safe to delete btmp from log on ubuntu 14.04 rackapace server?

Tags: 14.04, server, log

Basically I want to clear unwanted log files from ubuntu 14.04 rackspace cloud server. as files are using too much space.

can I remove following log files from server ?

/var/log

> btmp (35.4 MB)
>
> driveclient.log (15 MB)

2. how to clean tmp files

> #df -m /tmp
>
> ```
>  Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
>
>  /dev/xvda1         40184 38508         0 100% /
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`btmp` logs failed attempts into your system. In theory this could mean someone is trying to brute force passwords. You can empty this file but should not remove it since software could crash when it expects the file to be there. To empty it from command line:

```
sudo > /var/log/btmp
```

If it gets filled quickly you really should investigate why.

`driveclient.log` is something specific to space rack. Again to empty it use...

```
sudo > /var/log/driveclient.log
```

Regarding this last you should have the following [files](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/cloud-backup-agent-logging-basics) (nore info in the link):

> **Agent file location (Linux)**
>
> Assuming a default installation, following are the agent file
>   locations on Linux systems:
>
> ```
> Configuration files: /etc/driveclient
> Logs: /var/log
> Startup script: /etc/init.d
> Application: /usr/local/bin
> PID file for running the agent: /var/run/driveclient.pid
> Database: search for a *.db file under /var/cache/driveclient
> ```

You can turn logging off or set the size of this log in /etc/driveclient and also how many compressed backups will be saved before the next one gets deleted.

Comment: It should be sudo > /var/log/btmp right? instead sudo > /var/log/btmp.log

Comment: @kamlesh.bar  yes sorry.

Comment: `sudo >` does the same as `>` by itself (except it might ask a password)  I think you mean `sudo truncate`